# this coin is about to launch to a huge amount of people and i think it's a scam. can anyone take a fast look?

Tags: binance

this coin will be pumping a lot in a couple of hours and i trully believe it's a scam. But i'm not sure how to check.
Can anyone take a look at the contract and check if there's a mint function or anyhing that could rug it ?

Comment: I'm concerned also about pause function

Comment: What is "this coin"? You didn't share a contract address.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot judge yourself if there is a risk or not, don't buy it.

If you need the advice to have someone, who is professional, to check it for you, hire professionals. Do not ask community for an advice. We are not here to do free work for shitcoin due diligence.